# MYSQL ORDER by Type and get 5 rows from each type with Total 20 rows

Tags: mysql, count, limit, max

I have this query "SELECT Name, Type FROM tabel WHERE Name LIKE :key ORDER BY Type LIMIT 0,25"
What I want to do is to get 5 rows from each Type and keep the total response to LIMIT 25

My table structure looks something like this:
Name | Type
A    | 1
B    | 2
C    | 4
D    | 2
E    | 2
F    | 4
G    | 1
H    | 2
I    | 2
J    | 2
so in the answer i want to get
A 1
G 1
B 2
D 2
E 2
H 2
I 2
C 4
F 4

I tried lots of thing but i can't do it. Can any one help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been trying to make a query that I found on the net to work with PDO to solve my problem and tried lots of scenarios till this worked:

```
        $query = "set @num := 0, @Type := ''";
        $query2 = "SELECT Name, Type, (SELECT(@num := if(@Type = Type, @num + 1, 1))) as row_number, ".
        "(@Type := Type) as dummy FROM table WHERE Name LIKE ? ".
        "GROUP BY Type, Name, SearchBy HAVING row_number < 6"; 
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query2);
            $stmt->execute(array($name));
            $count = $stmt->rowCount();
            $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

And this would give me 5 of each type as I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Group by type after order by :

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM
  ...
WHERE
  ...
ORDER BY
 type
GROUP BY
  type;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it would choose only one of each type and I need 5 of each type